# how to use the window object (or better way) to make dynamic property names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117153/1252748) that the window object can be used to dynamically make a property name within an object. What is the way this is done

I have a function like

```
function storeValues(){

    var info = {};
    $('.class1').each(function(index1, value1){
        $('.class2', $(this)).each(function(index2, value2){

            //so here I'd like to add a string to the property name
            //like 'param-' and 'detail-' so I could end up with a 
            //structure like 
            //info.param_0.detail_0
            //then
            //info.param_0.detail_1
            //info.param_1.detail_0
            //info.param_1.detail_1
            //info.param_1.detail_2
            info.'param_'index1.'detail_'index2 = $(this).find('.desired_input').val();

    });
}
```

Is this possible. Or is there a smarter way of doing it?

Comment: At least this is a wrong way. Try info['param_'+index1]['detail_'+index2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the `window`, the `[]` notation for accessing dynamic object property names is an aspect of the JavaScript language.

```
info['param_' + index1]['detail_' + index2] = $(this).find('.desired_input').val();
```

---

Of course, if `info['param_' + index1]` does not exist yet, you will have to create it as an empty object before setting its properties.

```
info['param_' + index1] = info['param_' + index1] || {};
info['param_' + index1]['detail_' + index2] = $(this).find('.desired_input').val();
```